# Issue with design and aggregation/queries

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I've been working on a small project which wouldn't mind some Mongo but I have some issues with the model and the queries.

I have went with a schema similar to:

```
let botSchema = new Schema({
                   botNumber : Number,
                   states : [
                       date : { type : Date, default: Date.now },
                       sold       : Number,
                       bought     : Number,
                       item_price : Number
                   ]});
```

I am automating a small group of bots in a local game and would like to have a complete transaction log of everything they do (I'd be pruning it manually once in a while).

I then need to support getting all transactions, transactions between a date range, and the last valid state/element of the array.

Any tips? :)